# Why emits CMake a CMP0022 warning although not using LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES?

Tags: cmake

In my whole code I never use LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES or something similar. All install, export and link_* command are used without.The only somewhat similar occurrence I was able to grep was in the build directory in the file lib/CMakeFiles/Export/lib/cmake/mylib-targets-noconfig.cmake:

> IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES_NOCONFIG "CXX"
>   IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES_NOCONFIG

Still, I get a CMP0022 warning:

> CMake Warning (dev) in lib/CMakeLists.txt: Policy CMP0022 is not set:
>   INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES defines the link interface.  Run "cmake
>   --help-policy CMP0022" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
>
> Target "mylib" has an INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES property.  This should
>   be preferred as the source of the link interface for this library but
>   because CMP0022 is not set CMake is ignoring the property and using
>   the link implementation as the link interface instead.
>
> INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES:

This happens when I link an external library to mylib. When I use CMake 2.8.12.1 which improved the handling of CMP0022 compared to 2.8.12 the number of warnings is massively reduced and I get only one warning per external library.

What causes the warning? From the documentation I don't get it.
What should I do to get rid of this warning? Is this compatible to older versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake 2.8.12.1 was released to address this issue. Please try that version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately CMake 2.8.12.1 just reduces the number of warnings to only one warning per external library. I clarified my question to include this piece of information.

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime there was a similar question posted to the CMake mailing list. Stephen Kelly answered there are three options. [[1](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-December/056627.html), [2](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-December/056628.html)] The one I liked most uses `LINK_PRIVATE` and `LINK_PUBLIC`. But it is only backwards compatible to CMake 2.8.9.

Comment: Stephen Kelly == steveire :)

And the options there mostly apply to KDE, but you're right that option 3 is the best one.

Answer (score -4):

Try putting this block:

```
IF(COMMAND CMAKE_POLICY)

&nbsp;&nbsp;CMAKE_POLICY(SET ???? OLD)

&nbsp;&nbsp;CMAKE_POLICY(SET ???? OLD)

ENDIF(COMMAND CMAKE_POLICY)
```

WHERE ???? is the name of the offending policy

I haven't read much about this yet, but I think is because they added a mechanism to set the target properties to avoid ambiguities when dealing with different targets, in any case, if a new version of CMake warns you about some policy you can set that policy to an old behavior.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/policy/CMP0022.html